# Only last Push Notification is received when my iPad is off

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification

I send i.e. 3 push notifications to my iPad (iOS 5.1.1) while the iPad is turned off.

When I turn the iPad on - only the last push notification is displayed in the notification centre.

I'm using Appoxee.com as my push server

Thanks for your help

Comment: Push are best effort (as I'm sure you know) plus I've found them inconsistent on iOS 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Quality of Service

Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.

If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to the device when it becomes available.

Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.

If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that were being stored for it are discarded.
```